# React dynamic table create

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make a calendar with **React**.

I can generate an array which contains this month dates.

But, I can't output it.

If I missed something, comment plz.

```
class Calendar extends Component{

  /* ... */

  render(){
    let data = ["", "", "", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, ""]
    return(
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>S</th>
            <th>M</th>
            <th>T</th>
            <th>W</th>
            <th>T</th>
            <th>F</th>
            <th>S</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          /* insert here dynamic data */
          /*
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>3</td>
            </tr>
          */
        </tbody>
      </table>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: I updated my code. Can you try and let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So generally to iterate an array of values and to display them. You should do something like below but sorry if you feel it's bad logic.

```
class Calendar extends Component{

  /* ... */

  render(){
    let rows = [];
    let columns = [];
    let data = ["", "", "", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, ""]
    for(let i=0; i < data.lenth; i++){
       columns.push(<td key={i}>data[i]</td>);
       if(i == 6){
          rows.push(<tr>{columns}</tr>);
          columns = [];
       }
       if(i == 13){
          rows.push(<tr>{columns}</tr>);
          columns = [];
       }
       if(i == 20){
          rows.push(<tr>{columns}</tr>);
          columns = [];
       }
       if(i == 27){
          rows.push(<tr>{columns}</tr>);
          columns = [];
       }
       if(i == 34){
          rows.push(<tr>{columns}</tr>);
          columns = [];
       }
    }

    return(
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>S</th>
            <th>M</th>
            <th>T</th>
            <th>W</th>
            <th>T</th>
            <th>F</th>
            <th>S</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {rows}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Np. What is ur actual expectation?

Answer (score 1):

Use a loop to display all elements from your array.

```
<tr>
{[...data].map((x, i) => (
    <td key={i}>{x}</td>
))}
</tr>
```